# What should I use to build database that I can edit after launch?

Tags: ios, database

I want to build IOS app, in the app I want to present my data.
The data should be read only (the user or anyone else but me can't edit it) but I want to have the option to add or remove items from/to the database.
What should I use?
I don't want to bundle the database in the app and use FMDB because I want to be able to edit it after launch.

Comment: http://hayageek.com/ios-sqlite-tutorial-create-select/

Comment: why not using RESTful instead of database?

Comment: Sound good to use REST but I have no idea how to use it or implement it. You have a beginners tutorial you can refer me to?